# Interpolating issue during Marching Cube on a scalar field

Tags: c++, algorithm, marching-cubes

I have a regular square grid wherein all my data points are stored at the centroid. I have a scalar field(range : 0->1) that indicates the amount of substance inside a cell. I am interested in identifying the interface of this substance inside the cell (for further processing and not for visualization).

I came across the Marching cube  algorithm(http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/). Here I need the values at the corners of the cell. So I averaged the centroid values of the neighbouring cell. 
This averaging coupled with further linearization to find the points of intersection during "Polygonization" in MC is resulting in non-realistic interfaces such as this..

[image]

Here the gray cell is full of substance while its neighbours have minimal amount of substance. Ideally this should be very close to the boundary of the celtre cell. I feel this happens due to linear interpolation between 0.25 and 0 which leads it far off from its intended position.

Can something be done to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The Marching-Cubes-algorithm has one parameter that can be adjusted, namely the `isolevel`. In your example you seem to have chosen a value around `0.05` for the `isolevel`. When choosing a value just below `0.25` (e.g. something like `0.24`) the interfaces will be much closer to the center cell. But then you will have still unsatisfactory results when two cells with value `1` touch each other s.t. the corners will have an average value of `0.5`.

What you still can try: instead of averaging the cell values for computing corner values you can take the maximum cell value for the corner value and raise the `isolevel` to a value just below `1` (e.g. `0.9`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I take my isovalue as the cell centre value. For example the cell to the right of the centre cell has a isovalue of 0.01 because I want to know the interface the substance makes inside the cell when it occupies a volume of 0.01... Am I doing it wrong somewhere ?

Comment: The isolevel determines, where exactly the grid lines are intersected by the generated polyon. Usually you have one isolevel for the whole algorithm/polygon. (btw: if you had passed 0.01 as isolevel to the marching cubes algorithm or also only to single cells, I would expect that the resulting polygon (dashed line) is even bigger, almost running through the corners.)